# How to use web/api guard in the same time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In `auth.php` configuration file I have default setting:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

It means that by defauls will be used api authorization with `api_token`.
How to use web/api guard in the same time?

Because I have two parts of application, web and RESTfull.

When I use `'guard' => 'api'` and try to logout/Login from web version of application, I get error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::logout()
```

Comment: what the scenario? makes you to do that

Comment: Use middleware. `auth:web` will use web guard, `auth:api` will use api guard

Comment: I use it, but whatever get errors